# Surface area of parametric curve $x = \cos^{3} \theta$, $y= \sin^{3} \theta$ rotating around $x$-axis

Tags: calculus, area, parametric

Find the area of the surface obtained by rotating the curve about the $x - axis$.

$$x = \cos^{3} \theta$$
$$y = \sin^{3} \theta$$
$$0 < \theta < 2\pi$$

I've searched all around the internet and found:
[image]

But this quite doesn't make sense to me and neither does give me the correct answer as [image]
when rotated about x-axis, this part will not be counted as the surface area when multipled by two.  So, how could I solve this question?

Comment: I don't know what tis black-red scribble is supposed to demark, and what is 'this part' that you're speaking of. But the formula you found is correct. You can also take the limits to be $t\in[0,\pi]$, and not multiply by 2, result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The formula you found is correct, I don't understand what problem you have with it.

There's also another method:

You can parametrize the surface obtained with the rotation by
$$ \vec{r}(t,\phi) = (x(t,\phi),y(t,\phi),z(t,\phi)) = (\cos^3 t,\sin^3 t\cos\phi,\sin^3 t\sin\phi)$$ 
with $t\in[0,2\pi]$, $\phi\in[0,\pi]$ (because you only need half of the rotation to get the whole surface).
The area is then given by
$$ S = \int_0^{2\pi} dt \int_0^\pi d\phi \left|\frac{\partial\vec r}{\partial t}\times \frac{\partial\vec r}{\partial \phi}\right|$$

Answer (score 0):

The surface integral is

\begin{align}
A &= 2\int_0^1 2\pi y\sqrt{1+(y’_x)^2}dx\\
&= 4\pi \int_{\pi/2}^0 \sin^3\theta \sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}(-3\cos^2\theta\sin\theta)d\theta\\
&= 12\pi \int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^4\theta \cos\theta d\theta= \frac{12\pi}5
\end{align}